# How to restrict viewing of files and attachments to owner?

Tags: security

We have some sensitive documents which are uploaded as attachments to contact records. We want to restrict viewing of these documents to only the owner of these records.

how can we achieve this?

Comment: are you using lightning?

Comment: yes, we are using lightning

Answer (score 2):

Its very easy in lightning,

Create a field on formula file `is Contact Owner` of type boolean having formula `OwnerId ==  $User.Id`

Go to App Builder , remove `Related Lists` common component, and use `Related List Single`

From Related List Single, chose `Notes and Attachment` related list. Here you can set component visibility. and chose your field.

[image]

Note and Attachments will only be visible if the current user is the Owner of the contact

Comment: Interesting... But someone moves to classic they can see it?

Comment: Can we do it using permissions

Comment: Thats why I asked , is it classic or lightning. We have disabled classic for our user and hence they cannot switch .. This cant be done via permissions as there is no such thing as permission for Attachmentts. If User has access to a record, he can see its attachment no matter what. There can be as solution if you move from Attachment to Files, you can then customize who sees what.

Comment: Thanks.. i could have them all as files and review it